# Trying to send a message to multiple channels when receiving a message using discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I want to send a message to multiple channels using channel id's from any server.
I'm trying to make a discord.js code. I have a JSON file that has many channels' id . So, what I want is: if, in one of the channels, someone sent a channel there, then fetch the message and send it to every channel in the JSON file (except the channel which received the message).

****discord.js v12****

The JSON file is just like

```
blablabla:["id 1","id 2","id 3 ","id 4"]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please attempt to solve your problem first and then post a question to get help and clarifications about any specific problems you may come across.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like so:

```js
const chList = require("pathtoJSONfile");
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    let currentChannel = message.channel.id
    chList.forEach((x) => {
        if (x === currentChannel) return
        client.channels.cache.get(x).send(message.content)
    }
});
```

What are we exactly doing here? So, we are importing the array of channel IDs from the JSON file you mentioned and then looping through that array. Each time we loop through it we are trying to get the channel and send the original message's content ( seems like spyware already  ) just taking care if the `id` of the current channel matches one of the `id`s in the JSON file, we just use the `return` statement and do nothing.

### Some points to be noted.

Make sure you input your path to your JSON file properly, otherwise you may define the array of channels `id`s within the same file like so:

```js
const chList = ["Id1","Id2"];
```

Please further note that the `messageCreate` listener is available to discord.js v13. If you are on a version below it you can simply use the `message` listener.